# passing search text to ctags and getting file location as output

Tags: string, search, header, ctags

Is there a way to pass a **search string** to **ctags** and get the **filename (or path)** from which the search string is referenced?

For example, let's say that I have created a header file named **myHeader.h**
which has the definition for the functions **foo1()** and **foo2()**.

Now I include this header file in **test.c** and use the functions foo1() and foo2()

So, would I be able to get **myHeader.h** as the output by passing foo1() or foo2() as a parameter to ctags?

Does it even support that sort of thing?

Comment: Why not parse the tags file to obtain the exact same information?

Comment: @Vitor Pasring the the tag file is an available option, but if ctags can give me the result without parsing the tag file, that would make things much simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that is the purpose of ctags. This tool was always used to create an intermediate database of tags that is then processed/filtered by a second tool.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I guess **grep** would suffice my needs then.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Universal Ctags (https://ctags.io), readtags command included in the ctags source tree supports this use case.

Generating tags file:

```
$ cat myHeader1.h 
int  foo1(void);
$ cat myHeader2.h 
int  foo2(int);
$ ctags --version | grep Universal
Universal Ctags 5.9.0, Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
$ ctags -o my.tags --kinds-C++=+p myHeader1.h myHeader2.h
$
```

`--kinds-C++=+p` is for tagging prototype declarations.

Reporting the file name where the name is declared:

```
$ ./readtags -t my.tags -F '(list $input "\n")' foo1
myHeader1.h
$ ./readtags -t my.tags -F '(list $input "\n")' foo2
myHeader2.h
```

`-F` specifies the format of the output.
More examples are found in https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/man/readtags.1.html .

If you use the latest ctags getting from github.com/universal-ctags/ctags and the input source files are small enough, you can use a pipeline for getting the same output:

```
$ ctags -o - --kinds-C++=+p myHeader1.h myHeader2.h  | ./readtags -t - -F '(list $input "\n")' foo2
myHeader2.h
$ ctags -o - --kinds-C++=+p myHeader1.h myHeader2.h  | ./readtags -t - -F '(list $input "\n")' foo1
myHeader1.h
```

NOTE: both ctags and readtags generate temporary files.